# Creating a web-service client with a known but inaccessible wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, wsdl, client

We have been provided with a wsdl and xsd schema by a company we are working with via email. The web-services we are interfacing with are accessed through a IPsec tunnel. There are local references(on their end) in the published WSDL which means we cannot consume it.

1st question: Is this a common setup? I thought the point of having a WSDL was not only to define the contract but to also expose the service to consumers.

I can easily generate client/server code off of the provided WSDL using wsimport, wsconsume, etc.. I know when my generated client makes a call to my generated service it produces the correct message I need.

2nd Question: Is there an easy way to route this to a different soap address?

I just want to be able to do something like:

```
SalesTaxService svc = new SalesTaxService();
SalesTax tax = svc.getSalesTaxPort()
tax.getRate("NY");
```

But not use the soap address defined in the WSDL. I would like to avoid writing a bunch of dispatch clients for each method.

Am I missing something?

*In response to skaffman:
This is what was generated. It defaulted to wsdlLocation as a name *shrug*

```
   @WebServiceClient(name = "SomeService")
   public class SomeService_Service extends Service {

    public SomeService_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);            
    }

    public SomeService_Service(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, new QName("urn:some_service", "SomeService"));   
    }
  }
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/863561/147763

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out why I was having a problem. I was assuming that the wsdlLocation had to be the WSDL that the actual service was publishing. This of course is not the case. The solution is to package a local WSDL with the correct SOAP:Address for the actual service into the client.

*edit*
I found out that you can alter the endpoint address programmatically without having to alter the actual WSDL:

```
HelloService service = new HelloService (
  this.getClass().getResource("originalHello.wsdl"),
  new QName("http://example.org/hello", "HelloService "));
HelloPort proxy = service.getHelloPort();

Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider)proxy ).getRequestContext();
ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.HTTP_CLIENT_STREAMING_CHUNK_SIZE, 8192);
ctxt.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://new/endpointaddress");

proxy.sayHello("Hello World!");
```

Credit goes to : [Jianming Li](http://jianmingli.com/wp/?p=585)

Answer (score 5):

> I thought the point of having a WSDL
>   was not only to define the contract
>   but to also expose the service to
>   consumers.

No, WSDL is purely a descriptive tool, it has no real runtime role. The web service operates completely independently of the WSDL. It's not uncommon for the WSDL to not be exposed.

> Is there an easy way to route this to
>   a different soap address?

That depends entirely on what web service implementation you're using, and you don't say, although I'm guessing JAX-WS. If that's the case, the artifacts that JAX-WS's tools generate allow you to pass in the URL to the client stub constructors, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am using JAX-WS. The problem is that the URL I would pass in is that of the WSDL which is inaccessible.  I can generate my own service and point the client to my own service implementation but that won't go to the actual SOAP:Address that I want to interface with.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought the URL to the stub constructor was the URL of the web-service endpoint, not the URL of the WSDL. This is why I don't like JAX-WS..... well, one of the reasons....

Comment: Not 100% sure but look above at what was generated. It named wsdlLocation specifically. Besides If I try putting in the endpoint address it simply won't work at all (when I try connecting to a local service)... But the ?wsdl address works fine.