# Creating a web-service client directly from the source

Tags: java, maven-2, wsdl, jax-ws

I am trying to generate the WS client jar directly from the @Webservice class(es).

Let's take this example :

```
package com.example.maven.jaxws.helloservice;
   
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class Hello {
     public String sayHello(String param) {
        return "Hello " + param;
     }
}
```

I can generate a war file and use GlassFish to serve this web service, and from there I can use the glassfish WSDL URL to generate the client sources.

What I am trying to do is to skip the GlassFish part.
From my maven project defining the webservice, I would like to use the jaxws-maven-plugin to create the client classes but I cannot find any way to specify the actual URL of the webservice.

It should be possible, right?

@see also [Creating a web-service client with a known but inaccessible wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097789/creating-a-web-service-client-with-a-known-but-inaccessible-wsdl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `<wsdlLocation>` option to give the location of the service where the WSDL file is going to be available after deployment.

> **Using -wsdlLocation switch**
>
> There is another easy way to do it -
>   just run wsimport with -wsdlLocation
>   switch and provide the WSDL location
>   value which is relative to the
>   generated Service class and you need
>   to put this WSDL file at this relative
>   location.

[See the post for more details](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/vivekp/archive/2007/06/portable_client.html).

Comment: So you say that you should download a copy of the WSDL from a previous run.  For Metro this might be hard as it contain additional lookups.

Answer (score 7):

Creating a web service client application always starts with an existing WSDL file (unlike developing a web service provider) and, even if this is not the only way,  I'd suggest to use the `wsimport` tool (see [5 Techniques for Creating Java Web Services from WSDL](http://java.dzone.com/news/5-techniques-create-web-servic) for other options but I won't cover them).

So, in your client project, add the following snippet to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <wsdlUrls>
              <wsdlUrl>
                http://localhost:8080/helloservice/HelloService?wsdl
              </wsdlUrl>
            </wsdlUrls>
            <packageName>com.example.maven.jaxws.helloclient</packageName>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
<bulid>
```

The `jaxws-maven-plugin:wsimport` mojo is bound by default to the `generate-sources` life cycle phase so running any phase posterior to `generate-sources` will trigger the `jaxws:wsimport` goal.

Note that this is really a minimal configuration. If you want more details/control, check  the documentation of the [`wsimport`](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html) mojo.

For example, to use files instead of URLs for the WSDL (and to generate Java code in a location more compliant with maven best practices), use:

```
<configuration>
  <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsimport</sourceDestDir>
  <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
  <wsdlFiles>
    <wsdlFile>foo.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    <wsdlFile>bar.wsdl</wsdlFile>
  </wsdlFiles> 
  ...
</configuration>
```

**Update:** To invoke a pre-configured stub (using the endpoint address from the WSDL), the code is:

```
Hello port = new HelloService().getHelloPort();
String result = port.sayHello("Duke!");
```

In order to invoke an endpoint whose address is different from the one specified in the WSDL, define the new endpoint URL and the QName:

```
URL endpoint_new = new URL( "NEW_ADDRESS_HERE" );
QName qname = new QName( "http://"+"ORIGINAL_PACKAGE", "SERVICENAME" );
Hello port = new HelloService( endpoint_new, qname ).getHelloPort();
```

where `ORIGINAL_PACKAGE` is the package where the service published in, `SERVICENAME` is the name of the service we need, for example, `HelloService`.

Comment: If I use your last solution (generate the client from a wsdl file), then the client jar will not contain the URL of the webservice. Is there a way to provide it with maven ? I just see the <wsdlUrl/> tag but nothing else...

Comment: When using `@WebService` with Metro, the WSDL is generated at runtime, and hence is probably not available at compile time.