# Does a WSDL file need to be published on a server to consume its services?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jax-ws

I had a WSDL file locally for a service. I used it to generate the my java proxy client using eclipse.

Now when I invoke this service, it fails. The error i get is that java client is looking for the same WSDL (from which I generated proxy client) file published on the web server. (looks for https://myservice.com/xyz?wsdl type URL for WSDL)

so, what I want to clarify is that does it require to publish WSDL file on web server to use the service? How can I get my client working with the service?

Comment: Is this a JAX-RPC client or a JAX-WS one? JAX-WS clients will look for the WSDL by default. There are mechanisms to configure this from occurring though.

Comment: it is a JAX-WS client. what do you mean by JAX-WS client will look for wsdl by default. also what will be the default location of wsdl for JAX-WS client

Comment: I'll point you to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764772/jax-ws-loading-wsdl-from-jar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163586/jax-ws-client-whats-the-correct-path-to-access-the-local-wsdl . Unfortunately I will have to mark this question as a duplicate. **Edit:** The second question has a more comprehensive answer.