# sun-jaxws.xml - Loading wsdl and xsds from jar

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm using a contract first approach to build JAX-WS Webservices. The clients pick the wsdl and xsd resources from a client jar as specified in this SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18323853/775467 by using the wsdlLocation attribute.

Is it possible to do the same on the server side. i.e is it possible to use wsdls and referred xsds from a jar in sun-jaxws.xml

```
<endpoint name='TestService'
        implementation='provider.server.AddNumbersImpl'
        wsdl='WEB-INF/wsdl/Test.wsdl'
        service='{http://example.org}TestService'
        port='{http://example.org}TestServicePort'
        url-pattern='/test'/>
```

I know that I can refer to wsdls in the WEB-INF directory as in the above snippet but I don't want to package the wsdls and xsds into the WAR but would like to pick them up from a shared library jar deployed to the server in the same way how the client code picks the wsdl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no possibility to change the location of the wsdl file. The wsdl attribute at sun-jaxws.xml must have the prefix "WEB-INF/wsdl". Else JAX-WS generates and publishes a new WSDL. If you take a look at the source code of jaxws-ri, you can find the implementation at the class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser, method getPrimaryWSDL:

```
...
if (wsdlFile != null) {
        if (!wsdlFile.startsWith(JAXWS_WSDL_DD_DIR)) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Ignoring wrong wsdl={0}. It should start with {1}. Going to generate and publish a new WSDL.", new Object[]{wsdlFile, JAXWS_WSDL_DD_DIR});
            return null;
        }
...
}
```